# Парсинг товаров

Tags: база-данных, c++, синтаксический-анализ

**Предисловие**
Я открываю свой магазин, и мне нужно спарсить товары с сайта поставщика. На `PHP` я решил этого не делать, т.к. очень долго и не хватает памяти у него или Тайм Аут, в общем геморой один. Да и хотелось полосу статуса, чтобы видеть на каком шаге сейчас программа. 
На `PHP GUI` есть такая возможность, но там оперативку съедает сразу, и после некоторого кол-ва товаров выдаст ошибку. Поэтому решил на крутом Си это сделать) Сначала спарсить, потом отправить на PHP обработчик на сервере, чтобы тот забил в БД.

**Ну, в общем вопросы:** 
Какой функцией в Си++ нужно открывать страничку и записывать в переменную исходный код странички?  
Какой функцией можно уже парсить товары, типа preg_match (из `PHP`)?
Ну и какой функцией можно открыть удалённую страницу, чтобы забить в БД товар? 
А, и ещё можно ли как-то забивать в локальную `MySQL` БД?

**UPD:**
Итак, после раздумий и помощи здесь, C++ и Python отбросились, т.к. в первом это очень трудно реализовать, а в Пайтоне нужно глубоко разбираться, чтобы сделать оконное приложение. Также я узнал, что PHP на самом деле не кушает много памяти, просто видимо я что-то не так делал. Ну, пробуем PHP и Devel Studio, с этим инструментом у меня огромный опыт. Сразу как напишу программу, отпишусь с каким проблемами столкнусь.

Вот код, который быстро съедает память, что делаю не так?:
При создании формы выполняется:

```
    ini();
    gui_propSet(c("scrollBox1")->VertScrollBar, Tracking, True); 
    gui_propSet(c("scrollBox1")->HorzScrollBar, Tracking, True);
    function ini(){
    global $array_download;
$f = file_get_contents('audiofiles.html');
$f = str_replace('&amp;','&',$f);
$f = str_replace('?','',$f);
preg_match_all('#<input type="hidden" id="audio_info[0-9_-]*" value="(.*),[0-9]*">#Usi',$f,$mp3);
$mp3 = $mp3[1];
preg_match_all('#<b.*><a href="[^"]*" onclick="[^"]*">(.*)</a></b> – <span class="title"#Usi',$f,$singer);
$singer = $singer[1];
preg_match_all('#– <span class="title".*>(.*) </span>#Usi',$f,$name);
$name = $name[1];
for($c=0;$c<count($name);$c++){
$name[$c] = str_replace('<span class="match">','',$name[$c]);
$name[$c] = str_replace('</span>','',$name[$c]);
$name[$c] = substr(preg_replace('#<a href="\#"[^>]*>(.*)</a>#Usi','$1',$name[$c]),0,90);
}
$posY = 20;
$form = c("Form1");
$sbox = c("scrollBox1");
for($i=0;$i<count($name);$i++){
$label = new TLabel($form);
$splabel = new TLabel($form);
$pb = new TProgressBar($form);
$but = new TMImage($form);
$label->parent = $sbox;
$splabel->parent = $sbox;
$pb->parent = $sbox;
$but->parent = $sbox;
$but->loadFromFile("download.png");
$but->w = 16;
$but->h = 16;
$pb->visible = false;
$label->caption = trim($singer[$i]).' - '.trim($name[$i]);
$but->cursor = crHandPoint;
$but->nameMP3 = $label->caption;
$but->fileMP3 = $mp3[$i];
$but->pb = $pb;
$but->speedl = $splabel;
$but->onClick = function($self){
DownLoadMP3(c($self)->nameMP3,c($self)->fileMP3,c($self)->pb,c($self)->speedl);
};
unset($but->nameMP3,$but->fileMP3,$but->pb,$but->speedl);
$array_download[$i]['nameMP3'] = $label->caption;
$array_download[$i]['fileMP3'] = $mp3[$i];
$array_download[$i]['pb'] = $pb;
$array_download[$i]['speed_label'] = $splabel;
$splabel->x = 16+$label->w+5;
$label->y = $posY;
$but->y = $posY;
$pb->y = $posY+15;
$splabel->y = $pb->y;
$label->x = 16;
$pb->x = 16;
$pb->w = $label->w;
$pb->h = 10;
$but->x = 16+$label->w+5;
$posY = $posY+36;
unset($label,$splabel,$pb,$but);
}
unset($posY,$sbox,$name,$mp3,$singer,$f,$form,$sbox);
}
```

Далее функция скачивания DownLoadMP3:

```
global $speed_label;
$speed_label = $speedl;
unset($speedl);
$pb->visible = true;
c("Form1->download1")->url = $mp3;
c("Form1->download1")->path = 'mp3/';
c("Form1->download1")->setProgress = $pb->self;
c("Form1->download1")->start();
rename(c("Form1->download1")->fileName,'mp3/'.DelBadSymbols($name).'.mp3');
```

Далее событие клик по кнопке:

```
global $array_download;
for($k=0;$k<count($array_download);$k++){
c('Form1')->caption = $array_download[$k]['nameMP3'];
DownLoadMP3($array_download[$k]['nameMP3'],$array_download[$k]['fileMP3'],$array_download[$k]['pb'],$array_download[$k]['speed_label']);
unset($array_download[$k]);
}
c('Form1')->caption = 'Готово!';
```

И событие для прогресс бара и вычисления скорости, которое выполняется при загрузке:

```
global $speed_label;
if($self->last_ti=="")
$self->last_ti = get_sec();
else{
$ti = get_sec()-$self->last_ti;
if($ti>=1)
$self->last_ti="";
}
if($ti>=1){
$speed = round(($pos-$self->last_pos)/1024);
$self->last_pos = $pos;
$speed_label->caption = $speed.' Kb/s';
}
$APPLICATION->processMessages();
```

Comment: Вы покажите сам код. Особенно регулярное выражение.

Какая конкретно выводится ошибка. (ошибка выводится сразу при парсинге первой страницы или только через определенное время?)
Какие настройки в php.ini и у веб сервера: Для тайм-аутов, предел оперативной памяти для процесса?

Если на странице сайта не 10000 товарных позиций, то никаких проблем быть не должно. php для этого лучше всех.

Comment: С DevelStudio не работал.
Вот лично мне, понять что здесь происходит, из такого кода,  очень сложно. 
Вероятнее всего проблема начинается с этой строки

    for($i=0;$i<count($name);$i++){

Единственное что могу порекомендовать, это вычислить точные места поедания памяти.
Для этого закомментировать участки кода и смотреть. Если превышения нет, убрать кусок комментария и снова смотреть. 
Тогда поняв откуда в основном  идёт превышение и как с этим бороться будет проще.

Или выложите полный код который можно запустить.

Comment: Я бы мог выложить сам проект, но это нужно, чтобы Девел Студия была устанавлена и я последую вашему совету.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если нужно только скачать страницу и поместить в переменную - тогда Вам нужно смотреть на библиотеку [curl](http://ru.libcurl.wikia.com/wiki/Libcurlru_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8) или, если есть желание поизобретать велосипед - писать на чистых сокетах.

Вторым шагом - парсить. Здесь три варианта:

- поиск по строке вручную - для мазохистов
- регулярные выражения. Но есть два лагеря программистов, один лагерь [верит что этого нельзя сделать](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), а другие - противоположную идею двигают.
- использовать dom парсер. Вот в qt [все уже есть](http://wincode.org/cpp/cpp-html-dom-qt).

Comment: думаю писать на чистых сокетах не вариант для человека, который задает вопрос "Какой функцией в Си++ нужно открывать страничку"

Comment: но я же должен показать альтернативы, что бы не быть предвзятым? а то придет кто то и скажет "используйте только raw socket'ы!, все остальное - велосипеды". :)

Comment: Да через регулярки без проблем могу спарсить, мне лишь нужно знать какой функцией.

Comment: регулярки есть в бусте и в qt. В последнем стандарте с++ они также есть, но некоторые компиляторы очень хитро их реализуют (не реализуют совсем).

Comment: @KoVadim, кстати, по поводу регулярок, насколько я помню, gcc компилил код, но он, при этом, не работал :) Не подскажите, как с этим обстоят дела сейчас?

Или под (не реализуют совсем) вы имели введу в т.ч. gcc?

Comment: проверил, брал этот [пример](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/). gcc 4.8.1 и clang 3.3 скомпилировали и похоже отработали правильно.

Comment: @KoVadim, ок, спасибо

Да, C++ развивается... Уже даже стандартные регулярки, кое-где, нормально работают :)

Comment: работаю в основном с с++, но регулярки мне всё равно в питоне больше всего нравятся. Ты же один раз соберёшь всё, а потом только новые товары будешь добавлять иногда, почему питон не подходит, тем более ты работал на нём уже.

Comment: человек пишет - памяти не хватает:).

Answer (score 3):

[@mctrane](/users/1720/mctrane), при подходе:

```
 прочтем все в переменную, а потом распарсим
```

почти никакого выигрыша от Си (С++) Вы не получите. Внутри ведь ПХП сделан на том же Си.

Реально здесь можно выиграть на *совмещении* чтения, разбора данных и их записи в базу (возможно в другом процессе), т.е. для получения эффективной реализации Вам придется спустится на другой уровень алгоритмов.

Comment: Злой вы! +1.

Comment: только avp забывает, что в пхп есть уборка мусора и накладные расходы. А так, да, это надстройка над Си.

Но честно, я не представляю, что там автор такого парсит, что ему не хватает памяти.

Comment: @KoVadim: Это вы не представляете, а для талантливого человека нет преград. :-) Хотя я тоже не представляю.

Comment: @KoVadim, нужно сохранять картинки также, именно они и забьют память, по крайне мере 10 музыкальных файлов мне выдавали ошибку, что моей оперативки не хватает. На форуме PHP GUI мне не сказали как решить эту проблему, код примитивный, там неоткуда взяться лишней забивки памяти. Именно поэтому у меня сложилось плохое впечатление о PHP-win приложениях

Comment: @mctrane, если Вы просто положите входные данные в файл (без парсинга, просто для теста), то какой его размер?

--

Попробуйте описать свою задачу (редактируйте свой вопрос, делайте  дополнения и как-то выделяйте их) более конкретно, с деталями, посмотрим как ее можно решить.

Просто сейчас Вы спрашиваете некие "частности", ответы на которые, без увязки с общей архитектурой приложения, скорее всего ничего не дадут.

Comment: @avp ну точно не знаю, там же постранично, ну думаю 500-1000Кб, ну точно не больше 1 мегобайта, это без картинок. Я не знаю почему, но памяти сжирает больше, чем весит что-то. Как раз делал скачку из ВК, но парсилось не с ВК, а просто с файла с ссылками на аудио. И вот 10 файлов, это не больше 100 МБ и уже мне пишет что занято уже 1Гб оперативы. Из-за чего - не понятно, поэтому и не рискую сейчас писать парсер на PHP

Comment: Т.е. у Вас по ходу считывания "раскрываются" все ссылки? 

Именно такое поведение Вам нужно?

Comment: Да, начинает со страницы с товарами, например с браслетами. Там к пример 15 страниц (сайт очень огромный, там публикуют разные люди свои товары, ну типа ebuy, только это не аукцион). И вот мне нужно открыть каждый товар на странице, спарсить его, потом перейти на следующую страницу и там все товары. И я вот боюсь опять мне PHP из-за такого процесса начнёт мозги выносить. Я привык - если большой цикл, значит проблемы точно будут. Может это из-за прогрессбара? Может он память жрёт?

Comment: @mctrane

Вы покажите как эти файлы сохраняете в памяти. Может у вас множественное копирование идет.
Код покажите. 
Если требуется "большой" цикл в PHP, значит обязательно будут большие проблемы(не высвобождаете не нужную память). 
Без демонстрации кода ничего не добьетесь.

Comment: Отправил тот код апдейтом, посмотрите, может поймёте в чём забивка памяти, мне кажется это из-за прогресс бара и учёта скорости

Answer (score 2):

Было бы отлично, если бы поставщики тебе xml отдавали. Тогда просто парсишь без проблем, например www.sourceforge.net/projects/tinyxml или code.google.com/p/pugixml/ . Уточните в каком виде данные у поставщика?

Comment: К сожалению поставщик не знает, что он мой поставщик)) Парсить надо с сайта.

Comment: @mctrane, а почему вы решили что вам нужен именно C++? В моем представлении, например, связка Node.js + jsdom куда предпочтительнее (упиратся задачу все-равно будет в IO, да и написать и поддерживать будет легче). Даже если вас такая связка не устраивает, на мой взгляд, юзать C++ для такой задачи, при условии, что вы не обладаете хорошими знаниями языка (я сделал вывод что вы таковыми не обладаете), неоправданный overhead, да и я более чем уверен, что производительность для этой задачи не так важна, да PHP тут не подходит, но не стоит сразу бросатся в крайности (в вашем случае - C/C++).

Comment: Ну Си у меня хотя бы в преспективах, я его учить собираюсь, когда в универ поступать буду. Ну на таком же уровне Пайтон знаю, там можно легче эту задачу осуществить? Node.js ну вообще не понимаю что такое, для меня это файл расширения javascript.

Comment: python тоже подойдет, только я не знаю что именно там используется для разбора HTML, но, как я понял по вашему комменту выше, вы знаете толк в извращениях и собираетесь парсить HTML регуляркой, в связи с чем, либа для разбора вам не понадобится.

Comment: я раньше парсил с помощью питона + lxml. Но у питона своеобразное отношение к юникоду. Он хоть и заявляет его полную поддержку, но в консоль хочет писать только в аски (в юникодную консоль).

Теперь перешел на перл + `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath` и радуюсь жизни. Быстро, красиво. (да, некоторые люди не понимают перл, но если его в виме редактировать - самое оно:) ).

Comment: Точно ,есть же готовые классы которые разбирают страницу на объекты. Ранее я предпочитал регулярки для опыта, и парсинг страниц - идеально подходит для этого, щас уже умею пользоваться, поищу либы по разбору, разбирусь с pyQT) Просто охото, чтобы с интерфейсом было)) А вот то, что ты предложил, это Java, да?

Comment: @KoVadim - perl замечательный язык, просто многие perl программисты пишут так, что никакой обфускации, после, не требуется, более того, ходят легенды, что обфускация кода самых бородатых перловиков приводит к увеличению его размера :)

Comment: @mctrane никакую java я не предлагал.

Comment: KoVadim, это я алексу. Я предпочитаю Пайтон использовать, но возможно сюда пишу не по теме, но есть ли программа, которая может визуализировать построение программы? Т.е. чтобы не ручками писать код, который вставит в окошко T_Button, а как Visual Basic например?))

Comment: @mctrane - нет, это не java, это javascript. В интернете полно примеров по сабжу. Вообще достаточно ознакомится с https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom readme.

Comment: @KoVadim и как же vim позволяет избавиться от недостатков perl'а? perl в любом редакторе штука страшная. Почти как php.

Comment: да никак. потому что в перле нет недостатков. Недостатки в нем видят те, кто говорит, что у вима есть два режима - бибикать и портить текст. (расшифровка: кривая сложности у вима и перла сильно резкая и не все могут так просто осилить сразу. То, что вим помогает перлу - это такой юмор, на который @alexlz также попался :).)

Сравнивать перл с пхп... это как рассуждать о том, как лучше писать деструктор в java (!!! это тоже ЮМОР!!)

Comment: @KoVadim продолжение данной дискуссии -- флуд в чистом виде, но отрицать влияние перла на пхп ну никак нельзя. Тут дело даже не в общих предках. Явно просматривается прямой наследование.

Answer (score 1):

А какое количество товаров вы парсите? Миллионы? Сильно сомневаюсь.

"Не хватает памяти у него или Тайм Аут, в общем геморой один" и "после некоторого кол-ва товаров выдаст ошибку":  почему вы решили, что виноват в этом PHP, а не написанная вами программа? Зачем вам C++, в котором прострелить ногу в разы легче? А, ну да скорость: готовьтесь получать SEG_FAULT-ы со скоростью 100500 в секунду.

Comment: Я делал сохранение аудио через PHP и не хватало памяти, а мне нужно много картинок сохранять. И на вопрос как сделать правильно, мне ничего не ответили.

Answer (score 1):

Язык и его приспособленность под задачу тут вообще не причем. Есть готовые инструменты для этого дела.

Например, scrapy ( http://scrapy.org/ ), если под Python.

Если Вам для решения конкретной этой задачи, а не для практики в программировании, то именно готовый инструмент и следует взять за основу.